# Is values() of ConcurrentHashMap thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I'm new to Java8 and working on a problem where multiple threads (~10) are writing values to a Concurrent Hash Map. I have another dedicated thread which reads all the values present in Concurrent Hash Map and returns them (every 30 seconds). Is iterating over result of values() method the recommended way of fetching results without getting Concurrent Modification Exception?

**Note: I am perfectly fine with getting stale data**

I went over the official docs which says:

*Retrieval operations generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations . Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException.*

However doc of values() method says:

*Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map*

Is the below code thread safe?

```
for (String name: myMap.values()) {
     System.out.println("name": + name);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is thread safe.

Comment: You just quoted the answer: *"Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration"*. That statement covers `entrySet()`, `keySet()`, `keys()`, `values()`, and `elements()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is iterating over result of `values()` method the recommended way of fetching results without getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Yes.  It is the recommended way, and you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

As the package level javadoc states:

> *Most concurrent Collection implementations (including most Queues) also differ from the usual java.util conventions in that their Iterators and Spliterators provide weakly consistent rather than fast-fail traversal:*
>
> - *they may proceed concurrently with other operations*
> - *they will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`*
> - *they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.*

---

> Is the below code thread safe?
>
> ```
>   for (String name: myMap.values()) {
>        System.out.println("name": + name); 
>   }
> ```

Yes ... with some qualifications.

Thread safety really means that the code works according to its specified behavior in a multi-threaded application.  The problem is that *you haven't said clearly what you expect the code to actually do*.

What we can say is the following:

1. The iteration will see values as per the previously stated guarantees.
2. The memory model guarantees mean that there shouldn't be any *nasty* behavior with stale values ... unless you mutate value objects after putting them into the map.  (If you do that, then the object's methods need to be implemented to cope with that; e.g. they may need to be `synchronized`.   This is moot for `String` values, since they are immutable.)

Comment: I get the exception when i write it like `myMap.values.toList()` which seems a bit off. i can imagine `toList` also performs some sort of iteration to copy the items but it runs on the `values` object which is supposed to be fail-safe, right?

Comment: I suspect that you have misdiagnosed the problem.  The javadoc says that `values()` returns a collection that is *weakly consistent*.  And that means that CCME cannot be thrown.  (And there is no `Collection.toList()` method: `myMap.values().toList()` would be a compilation error.)

Comment: Sorry. i got indeed too carried away too quick. `toList` is actually a kotlin extension function. but I still see the CCME issue.

Comment: Ah.  So you are actually talking about Kotlin.  This Q&A is not apropos to your problem. It is a Java question.  Ask a new question and be sure to tag it `[kotlin]` ... and include a minimal reproducible example so that people (Kotlin experts!) can investigate.